# retrieving javascript cookies in google app engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Does anyone know how to retrieve javascript cookies in gae python? I've seen complicated examples around the web, like cookiejar, but I think that module is too much for my simple site. I'm just trying to make a shopping cart that will take js cookies, send it to server-side code (python) for verification, and then post the data to google checkout.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this code would help with your problem, [w/ helpful link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass):

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(self.request.cookies.get('cookiename'))
```

If you are little bit confused JS cookies and the HTTP cookies are just the same. See [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/) for more clear explanation.
Cookies are always transferred between `server` and `client` within the `HTTP header`. In this code we are just using the '`Set-cookie`' header within the request from client in server. `request.cookies` is a Python `dict` with cookies inside.

Comment: seems so simple...I feel dumb now haha. Thank you!